# Angular 2 is not picking index.html as start page from build directory and give error give Status 403 error (Gulp)

Tags: angular, gulp, angular2-routing

I am trying to build my first Angular 2 app with Gulp in Visual Studio 2015 and it's an Asp.net 4.5.2 empty project. Project layout --> src and it has app folder and here are my files:

app.component.ts file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

    @Component({
        selector: "app",
        templateUrl: "./app/app.html"
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

        ngOnInit() {
            console.log("Application component initialized ...");
        }
    }
```

app.html file:

```
<p>Angular 2 is running ... </p>
```

main.ts file:

```
/* Avoid: 'error TS2304: Cannot find name <type>' during compilation */
///<reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts"/>

import {bootstrap} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

app.html, app.component.ts and main.ts are in src/app folder.

Here is my gulp.js file  on project root which compiles the typscript files and also pushes nodemodules into lib folder:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const del = require("del");
const tsc = require("gulp-typescript");
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const tsProject = tsc.createProject("tsconfig.json");


/**
 * Remove build directory.
 */
gulp.task('clean', (cb) => {
    return del(["build"], cb);
});

/**
 * Compile TypeScript sources and create sourcemaps in build directory.
 */
gulp.task("compile", () => {
    var tsResult = gulp.src("src/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject));
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});

/**
 * Copy all resources that are not TypeScript files into build directory.
 */
gulp.task("resources", () => {
    return gulp.src(["src/**/*", "!**/*.ts"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build"))
});

/**
 * Copy all required libraries into build directory.
 */
gulp.task("libs", () => {
    return gulp.src([
            'core-js/client/shim.min.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
            'rxjs/**',
            'zone.js/dist/**',
            '@angular/**'
    ], { cwd: "node_modules/**" }) /* Glob required here. */
        .pipe(gulp.dest("build/lib"));
});

/**
 * Build the project.
 */
gulp.task("build", ['compile', 'resources', 'libs'], () => {
    console.log("Build finished ...")
});
```

In src folder I have systemjs.config.js and index.html files

systemjs.config.js file where I have map to point build app since I don't want to map it to the files that are in `src/app`. In the folder `build/app` which are moved after gulp build task or by building app it picks up from tsconfig.js and move to outDir to build folder:

```
(function (global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': '../build/app',
        'rxjs': '../build/lib/rxjs',
        '@angular': '../build/lib/@angular'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };

    var packageNames = [
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/router-deprecated',
        '@angular/testing',
        '@angular/upgrade'
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };

    // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
    if (global.filterSystemConfig) {
        global.filterSystemConfig(config);
    }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

My tsconfig.json file in project root:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "outDir" : "build/app",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

Above I am excluding node_modules and build directory which compiling ts files and placing them in build/app folder.

My typings.json file in project root folder:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332"
  }
}
```

My package.json file in root folder:

```
{
  "name": "angular2framework",
  "author": "Vijender Reddy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.1.5",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

My index.html page which is in src folder :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 TypeScript Gulp QuickStart</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="../build/lib/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../build/lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="../build/lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
</body>

</html>
```

I am pointing rsjx and zone.js from build directory which is created from gulp build task not from node_modules.

When I run my application it should pick index.html file by default but it doesn't pick it up and I get error:

> (Forbidden) http://localhost:34756/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

However when I am running the application when I am in index.html page, I can run the app but the url path is : http://localhost:57722/src/index.html

It is src/index.html, which I don't want. I want to pickup index.html as default and the url http://localhost:57722 should work even if I am on any file in project not just on index.html. It should automatically pick from build directory which is create by gulp build task.

Answer (score 1):

pretty old question but thought of posting my solution here
does your gulpfile.js have a task for starting webserver
something similar to below

```
gulp.task('webserver', function() {
gulp.src('app')
    .pipe(webserver({
        livereload: true,
        open: true
    }));
```

});

in the above code check **gulp.src('app')** and make sure your index.html file is  in the path given.